# How to I find the original row index of a table in a google visualization if I have a filtered rows view

Tags: google-visualization, rowfilter

I'm using Google Visualization.  I have a data table which I have filtered using getFilteredRows()

When I select a row in the filtered table the row index returned matches the on-screen row index but I need to be able to return the original row index from the underlying source data table.

Is that possible?

I've seen a couple of posts that use variations on

table.getDataTable().getTableRowIndex(currentRow)

but both of those methods don't seem to be available for use anymore?

Anybody know a solution?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTableRowIndex` is a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_2) method

on your chart wrapper, if you set the `dataTable` property to a data **view**,
then you can use...

```
chartWrapper.getDataTable().getTableRowIndex(currentRow)
```

however, if the `dataTable` property is an actual data **table**,
this method would not be available (because it is a data view method)

---

if using a data table and the chart wrapper's `view` property to set `rows`,
find the actual row by using...

```
chartWrapper.getView().rows[currentRow]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2012', 900, 700, 200],
    ['2013', 890, 600, 290],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  var chartTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    view: {
      rows: data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 1,
        minValue: 1000
      }])
    }
  });

  var testDiv = document.getElementById('test_div');
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chartTable, 'ready', function () {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartTable.getChart(), 'select', function () {
      testDiv.innerHTML = '';
      var selection = chartTable.getChart().getSelection();
      for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        var selectedRow = selection[i].row;
        var dataTableRow = chartTable.getView().rows[selectedRow];
        var values = '';
        for (var col = 0; col < data.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {
          if (values !== '') {
            values += ' -- ';
          }
          values += data.getValue(dataTableRow, col);
        }
        values += '<br/>';
        testDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', values);
      }
    });
  });

  chartTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="test_div"></div>
```